# How to create JSON from Nested java class

Tags: java, json, reflection

I am trying to create JSON object from java object. My java class has so many objects and sub objects as members. It is nested to 4-5 level. How do I create the json from this structure? I am trying using java reflation to get fields and sub fields but not able to add them in proper way to form a json.

Comment: try Gson https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: try `ObjectMapper` https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Comment: hint: you need to be able to serialize every nested object too

Comment: If I use gson or jackson it will gives StackOverflow exception. I want to create json manually.

Comment: if you have child objects that have reference to parent objects then you will see this exception you can avoid it using transient https://www.baeldung.com/gson-exclude-fields-serialization